# Is the below method considered as an insertion sort?

Tags: java, sorting

Is the below method considered as an insertion sort?

```
for( int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
    for(int j=i;j>0;j--){
        if(arr[j]<arr[j-1]){
            int temp=arr[j];
            arr[j]=arr[j-1];
            arr[j-1]=temp;
        } else { break };
    }
}
```

Comment: That is propadly bubble sort - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/ vs https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/

Comment: Yes, but you need to add one more if statement after swapping if. Otherwise, your program will run for O(n^2) even in best case

Comment: @VenkataGogu like what ?

Comment: It is somewhat insertion sort, but without its largest benefit: Insertion sort has a best-case time complexity of *O(n)*.

Comment: `if(arr[j]>=arr[j-1]) break`

Comment: @VenkataGogu it would be easier to replace the second `for` loop with a `while`-loop: `int j = i; while(j > 0 &&  a[j - 1] > a[j]) {...}`

Comment: @Turing85 I agree, but that's how actually insertion sort code look like and I don't think he needs to post it to verify whether it is insertion sort or not.

Comment: @VenkataGogu iv updated the code. Does it work now ?

Comment: Yes, test it and if it won't work then post bug here! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

yes.and your program will run for o(n^2) case.